# derivation of the standard normal loss function to an algebraic form

Tags: calculus, integration, normal-distribution

We have the following loss function of the standard normal distribution:

$ \int_z^\infty (x-z)\phi(x) dx$

where $\phi(.)$ is the pdf of the standard normal distribution.

In a book I'm reading, they lay out the following properties:

$\phi(-z) = \phi(z)$,

$\Phi^0(z) = 1-\Phi(z)$,

$\Phi^0(-z) = 1-\Phi^0(z) = \Phi(z) $,

$\phi'(z) = -z\phi(z)$

And then they say:

with these relations, the loss function can be written in terms of $\phi$ and $\Phi^0$ as

$-z\Phi^0(z)+\phi(z)$

Anyone an idea how we can get from these relations to the algebraic form of the loss function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can perform a direct computation:

$$\int_z^\infty (x-z)\phi(x) dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^\infty (x-z)\exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2}\right) dx\\
=\frac{-z}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^\infty \exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2}\right) dx+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^\infty x\exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2}\right) dx
$$

By substitution the last integral is $\displaystyle \frac{\exp\left( -\frac{z^2}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and by calling $\Phi(z)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^z\exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2}\right) dx$ you get:

$$\int_z^\infty (x-z)\phi(x) dx=-z(1-\Phi(z))+\displaystyle \frac{\exp\left( -\frac{z^2}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=-z(1-\Phi(z))+\phi(z)
$$

Sadly there is no analytical expression for $\Phi$ (but a lot of functions don't have easy "representations", even $e^x$ and $\sin(x)$ for are names for more complicated things).